# How to push after $http.post in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to find the right syntax to push a newly added item after it has been http.posted .

The syntax below doesn't give me any error, but doesn't push properly neither. Any ideas would help

```
$scope.insertAppointmentReminderEntry = function() { 

    $scope.add_reminder_time     = this.add_reminder_time;
    $scope.add_reminder_timeunit = this.add_reminder_timeunit;
    $scope.add_delivery_method   = this.add_delivery_method;
    $scope.add_delivery_contact  = this.add_delivery_contact;

    var data = {
         group_id               : $scope.groupid,
         appointment_id         : $scope.appointmentid,
         reminder_time          : $scope.add_reminder_time,
         reminder_timeunit      : $scope.add_reminder_timeunit,
         delivery_method        : $scope.add_delivery_method,
         delivery_contact       : $scope.add_delivery_contact
    };

      $http.post(urlApiAppointmentReminders + $scope.groupid, data).success(function(data, status) {

          var newItemNo = $scope.appointmentreminders.length+1;

          $scope.appointmentreminders.push($scope.appointmentreminders[newItemNo].data);
   })

   modalInstance.close();
};
```

html

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in appointmentreminders" class="row"  ng-style="{ 'border-top' : ( x.delivery_method != appointmentreminders[$index-1].delivery_method && $index != 0 ? '1pt solid #eee' : '0pt solid #eee' )}" style="border-top:1pt solid #eee; padding: 0.25em 0 0.25em 0" >

    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
               @{{x.time}} @{{x.timeunit}}@{{x.time > 1 ? 's' : ''}}  prior to appointment
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
               Reminder: @{{x.delivery_contact}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">                  
               <!-- delete this reminder -->
               <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="ctrl.removeItem($index)"></a>           
    </div>  

    </div> <!-- ng-repeat -->
```

html (modal to add new reminder)

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="addScheduleModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">Add a new appointment reminder</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">  
              <div class="col-sm-4" >
                   {!! Form::text( 'reminder_time', '30', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'ng-model' => 'add_reminder_time']) !!}
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8" >
                   {!! Form::select('reminder_timeunit', ['minute' => 'minutes(s)', 'hour' => 'hour(s)', 'day' => 'day(s)', 'week' => 'week(s)', 'month' => 'month(s)'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'ng-model' => 'add_reminder_timeunit']) !!}
              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 0.5em">  
              <div class="col-sm-4" >
                   {!! Form::select('delivery_method', ['eml' => 'Email'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'ng-model' => 'add_delivery_method']) !!}
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8" >
                   {!! Form::text('delivery_contact', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your email address', 'ng-model' => 'add_delivery_contact']) !!}
              </div>
        </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="insertAppointmentReminderEntry()">Save</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of duplication of property names by using a single object in `ng-model` and passing that object directly to `$http.post`. Aren't you wanting to push an object to the array?

Comment: I'm sure you're right, I get a bit lost in js. so for example, you mean changing $scope.add_reminder_time to $scope.reminder_time to match my API names

Comment: no use one object in `ng-model="reminder.time"` ... `ng-model="reminder.contact"`  .. etc ...then just send `$scope.reminder` in `$http.post` and skip all that manual copying of properties and individual variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient `$scope.appointmentreminders.push(data)`

or if you want to put the new data in specific position in the array, then do this
`$scope.appointmentreminders[newItemNo] = data`

But do not combine them in one line :)

Comment: need to confirm that `data` in response is the full object though since there are 2 variables `data`

Comment: Thanks! The push works, a new item is displayed, but I don't see the data for it though (unless I refresh, of course). Like @charlietfl said, I might have mess up my property names. Added code above

Comment: Just noticed that `data` contains `data: {"success": true}` hmm, how do I push `data` , the one that contains my data. Renaming it? I'll try that

Comment: Got it, changed `var data = {` to `var reminderdata = {` and use `reminderdata` for the push. Thanks guys